# Single Select() statement or multiple for transformation with multiple steps?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, optimization, query-optimization

In C#, I have a collection of objects that I want to transform to a different type. This conversion, which I would like to do with LINQ `Select()`, requires multiple operations in sequence. To perform these operations, is it better to chain together multiple `Select()` queries like

```cs
resultSet.Select(stepOneDelegate).Select(stepTwoDelegate).Select(stepThreeDelegate);
```

or instead to perform these three steps in a single call?

```cs
resultSet.Select(item => stepThree(stepTwo(stepOne(item))));
```

**Note**: The three steps themselves are *not necessarily* functions. They are meant to be a concise demonstration of the problem. If that has an effect on the answer please include that information.

Comment: The short answer is - it generally doesn't matter. Performance of the latter might be _slightly_ better, but https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ .

Comment: This will almost certainly be closed as opinion based - so I may as well share my opinion. I prefer the former since it shows the flow better (project with step 1, then 2 then 3). Plus you could have different parts of the projection (i.e. adding `Select` calls) done by different methods of your code. But the latter, honestly, is good enough since programmers are used to reading the steps in reverse anyway (since that is how most procedural code is written).

Answer (score 0):

Any performance difference would be negligible, but the definitive answer to that is simply "test it". The question would be more around readability, which one is easier to understand and grasp what is going on.

Cases where I have needed to Project on a Projection would include when working with EF Linq expressions where I ultimately need to do something that isn't supported by EF Linq so I need to materialize a projection (usually to an anonymous type) then finish the expression before selecting the final output.  In these cases you would need to use the first example.

Personally I'd probably just stick to the first scenario as to me it is easy to understand what is going on, and it easily supports additions for other operations such as filtering with `Where` or using `OrderBy` etc.  The second scenario only really comes up when I'm building a composite model.

```
.Select(x => new OuterModel
{
   Id = x.Id,
   InnerModel = x.Inner.Select(i => new InnerModel
   {
      // ...
   })
}) // ...
```

In most cases though this can be handled through Automapper.

I'd be wary of any code that I felt needed chaining a lot of `Select` expressions as it would smell like trying to do too much in one expression chain.  Making something easy to understand, even if it involves a few extra steps and *might* add a few milliseconds to the execution is far better than having the risk of needing to track down bugs that someone introduced because they misunderstood potentially complex looking code.